# Mongoose update function is giving null and not actually updating information

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My .findOneAndUpdate method is returning user as null and isn't ending up updating the information. Everything seems to be in order, I'm not getting any erros.

EDIT: I have made progress, I was able to finally update the GroupID, but its setting it as null. Instead of the passed in string.

```
router.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.id },
    {
      $set: { GroupID: req.body.GroupID }
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) res.send(err);
      else res.send("Account GroupID Updated" + user);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Above code is working perfectly fine in mine. Please check if there is something missing, may be field name.

Comment: @CalebN99 Whether  `req.body.id` is a string or ObjectId.Check for that..

Comment: @PrajwalBati  by field name you mean like something in the req.body? I am using Postman and I know it can have issues sometimes.

Comment: @Subburaj it's just a string I"m passing in

Comment: @CalebN99 It should be a ObjectId, so your condition is failing and so update is not happening.

Comment: Does User.find() return the user when you lookup on _ID?

Comment: @CalebN99 can you print the `err` message and show us what error you get

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I'm not getting any errors, that's the frustrating part haha, it feels like it should be working, but its just not, and I'm getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `req.body.id` to objectId as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);

 Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id }
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything it seems, and you would need to put that in the function not outside, otherwise req is undefined